# How to fix this text input in relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have XML like this :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/button1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the view like this :

[image]

How can I  fix that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to fix? Just the button?

Comment: Your views are not positioned correctly in your RelativeLayout. Use a LinearLayout with orientation horizontal to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `android:ems` attribute, which sets an exact width to the TextView (measured in EMs).

This overrides `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, and thus the text in the EditText overflows.

I'm guessing what you actually wanted was to set the size of the text, which should be done using `android:textSize` and SP units.